# Split magnet link with PHP

Tags: php, magnet-uri

I need two items in a magnet link:

```
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:0eb69459a28b08400c5f05bad3e63235b9853021&dn=Splinter.Cell.Blacklist-RELOADED&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.publicbt.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.istole.it%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.ccc.de%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337
```

the value of `btih`:

> `0eb69459a28b08400c5f05bad3e63235b9853021`

and the value of the first `udp`:

> `udp://tracker.com:80`

How to do this with PHP?

Comment: What attempt(s) have you made?

Comment: do you know any regex?

Comment: Try [hakre](http://stackoverflow.com/users/367456/hakre)'s [Magnet Link Library for PHP](https://gist.github.com/hakre/1949740).

Comment: Why are these answers even bothering with regex? Don't use a tool just to use it, use it when it is useful. I'm not saying the answers don't work, but they aren't decoding based on the format.
Here's my go at it: http://pastebin.com/DXDKVzFV

Answer (score 6):

As [parse_url()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) wont help in this situation your have to use regex to parse the string, and then further manipulate the string to get the trackers. So something like:

```
<?php 
$string = 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:0eb69459a28b08400c5f05bad3e63235b9853021&dn=Splinter.Cell.Blacklist-RELOADED&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.publicbt.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.istole.it%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.ccc.de%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337';

preg_match('#magnet:\?xt=urn:btih:(?<hash>.*?)&dn=(?<filename>.*?)&tr=(?<trackers>.*?)$#', $string, $magnet_link);

//0eb69459a28b08400c5f05bad3e63235b9853021
echo $magnet_link['hash'];

//Splinter.Cell.Blacklist-RELOADED
echo $magnet_link['filename'];

/*[trackers] => Array
(
    [0] => udp://tracker.com:80
    [1] => udp://tracker.publicbt.com:80
    [2] => udp://tracker.istole.it:6969
    [3] => udp://tracker.ccc.de:80
    [4] => udp://open.demonii.com:1337
)
*/
$magnet_link['trackers'] = explode('&', urldecode(str_replace('tr=','', $magnet_link['trackers'])));

//so to get first tracker
$magnet_link['trackers'][0];
?>
```

Comment: almost 5 years later and a response saves 3 hours of research, thanks

Answer (score 3):

As recommended in the question comments, there appear to be several existing libraries for magnet links - you should probably take a look at these.

If you want to do it yourself however, one way would be to regex for the values. Let's assume that your magnet link is assigned to a variable `$link` like so:

```
$link ='magnet:?xt=urn:btih:0eb69459a28b08400c5f05bad3e63235b9853021&dn=Splinter.Cell.Blacklist-RELOADED&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.publicbt.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.istole.it%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.ccc.de%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337';
```

A quick way to get each value is to run a separate `preg_match()` for each value - you could combine the two regexes and run `preg_match_all()` but let's keep it basic. We're going to use lookbehind assertions to try and find the required values.

```
// your magnet link
$link = 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:0eb69459a28b08400c5f05bad3e63235b9853021&dn=Splinter.Cell.Blacklist-RELOADED&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.publicbt.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.istole.it%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.ccc.de%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337';

// urls are encoded, let's reverse that
$link = urldecode($link); 

// first regex searches for 'btih:' and matches subsequent 
// word characters ([a-zA-Z0-9_])
// match(es) are captured as an array to $matchBtih
preg_match('/(?<=btih:)\w+/', $link, $matchBtih);

// same again, more or less, capturing word characters, colon and full-stop
// match(es) are captured as an array to $matchUdp
preg_match('/(?<=tr=)udp:\/\/[\w\:\.]+/', $link, $matchUdp);

// show results
var_dump($matchBtih, $matchUdp);
```

Should yield:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string '0eb69459a28b08400c5f05bad3e63235b9853021' (length=40)
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'udp://tracker.com:80' (length=20)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: haha you succumbed to the temptation too ;p

Comment: Snap! Ha... indeed! Funny you mention `parse_url()` - I initially assumed it was the way to go, but after some experimentation it would seem not!